# React ES6 syntax. Is it passing a function or calling a function immediately?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I am following the facebook tutorial and I have a question about the following code:

```
  handleClick(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }

    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      squares: squares,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
    });
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={this.state.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)} />;
  }
```

Somewhere there exists a `Square` component but don't worry about it right now. My question is what is going on in the `onClick` prop. What is on the right side? It looks like ES6 syntax for defining a Javascript function. But are we passing the handleClick function along or calling it? What does that reduce to in ES5?

Isn't `this.handleClick(i)` immediately calling the `handleClick` function and not passing it along?

Comment: Have you read the [MDN documentation about arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.handleClick(i)` <-- calls immediately.

`() => this.handleClick(i)` <-- is a function. `this.handleClick` will only be called when the wrapping function is called. The above can be rewritten in es5:

```
(function () { this.handleClick(i) }).bind(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the body of a function is a single statement, then (when using arrow syntax) you can omit the `{}` around it.

```
() => this.handleClick(i)
```

is equivalent to:

```
function () { this.handleClick(i); }.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you create a funtion in that way but you are not calling it in that moment. In that way the context of the created function remains the same as outside it (this). In this way you can call this.handleclick inside because this refers to the outside context

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has
>   its original meaning from the enclosing context.

From [arrow funtion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)